# Geometry Nodes - нow to get attribute value calculated on another frame?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'll try to be as short as possible. I've got a cube which chaotically flies around the scene and hits other random cubes from time to time. How can I store at which frame each cube have been hit to an attribute?

The collision algorithm itself is not important, the essential is how to transfer a data from one frame to another or, in other words, how to freeze an attribute once it suits certain conditions.

Comment: you need to use simulation nodes

Comment: Is there any way to do it in Blender 3.3?

Comment: **No** (there are some work arounds with duplication of node for certain situations, but it's still not getting information from previous frame's)